# AngularJS + PHP first page load

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, angularjs

I'm trying to set up a collection view (for a website - not a SPA).

I populate the view on the initial page load using traditional PHP "foreach", for SEO reasons and performance.

However on the second request (i.e. pagination/filter/sort) I would like to use AngularJS AJAX call and ng-repeat, is there a methodical way to prevent ng-repeat working on 1st page load? and is there a way to retrieve data synchronously?

Comment: do you mean that you want to allow first load without any JS and then add angular afterwards ?

Comment: Your views should not care where the data comes from, trying to disable view-features(ng-repeat) based on application state does sound like a bad idea. Rather try to seperate the data providers and the behaviour from the view.

Comment: @sylvain, yes, exactly